# Installing dlib with python bindings

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, anaconda, dlib

I'm trying to install and compile dlib with the python bindings. I tried cloning from github and running the commands:

```
mkdir build; cd build; cmake .. ; cmake --build .
python setup.py install
```

The first command works just fine but the second one gives me an error message:

```
4 warnings generated.
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/Users/username/anaconda/lib/libpython3.5.dylib', needed by `dlib.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: cmake build failed!
```

I tried running `pip install dlib` and I got the same exact error message.I also have both boost and boost-python installed via homebrew. I'm running on Mac OSX 10.10 and my version of python is: Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: I did not. I was a hard time getting the packages to play nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the filename from libpython3.6m.dylib to libpython3.6.dylib and the error went away.